# Cannot solved dependencies in Intelij

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a java project run on spring-boot and I got an error like this.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project example-user: Could not resolve dependencies for project co.id.brogomodi:example-user:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

and after that, I add these dependencies on my pom

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7.js6</version>
    </dependency>
```

But still got this error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project example-user: Could not resolve dependencies for project co.id.brogomodi:example-user:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js6 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

How did I suppose to do? i already run this command `mvn clean install`

Comment: Try "mvn clean install -U" the "U" option stands for forcing updates

Comment: still got the same error bro, btw thaanks

Comment: That does not work cause you are defining a version which does not exist in central repsository https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.lowagie/itext

Comment: Well, it's solved now because I am using the wrong version that doesn't provide by maven central. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any of `2.1.7.js6` version in the mvn repo (below url). Maybe other repository or use proper version.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext

Comment: yup, sorry my bad.